# HTML input inside ion-checkbox

Tags: css, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I am trying to put an html input to the right of ion checkbox but it is not working.

```
<label>
    <ion-checkbox ng-model="mode" ng-checked="checked">
        <input type="text">
    </ion-checkbox>
</label>
```

However, it works if text is being inserted

```
<label>
    <ion-checkbox ng-model="mode" ng-checked="checked">
        Label
    </ion-checkbox>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is working,

First I would add a placeholder value to the input box so you can see some sort of value.

```
<label>
   <ion-checkbox ng-model="mode" ng-checked="checked">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Input">
   </ion-checkbox>
</label>
```

Now that we see the input, we can't click on it, because ionic have added a class in the background to disable all pointer events on Inputs that are inside of Checkboxes.

To fix this, we simply add this to our css.

```
.item-checkbox .item-content{
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```